# Disadvantages of allowing equal values to be on either side of a self balancing binary tree?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, binary-tree

I'm trying to implement a self balancing binary tree for practice. One of the obvious internal operations is a [tree rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation). However, a tree rotation needs to take account the possibility that one of the child nodes is the same as the parent node; for example, if I have `left <= middle < right`, and my current node is

```
  0
 / \
0   1
```

Then I can't rotate clockwise. However, if I were to allow equal values to be found on either side, then I wouldn't have to worry about that.

So far I haven't found any problems...

- Insertions could still be fast. It could still follow `left <= middle < right` and balance as needed, or figure out the optimal side when inserting equal values
- Searches would be unaffected, assuming you just need to find a single occurences (no need to split if the values are equal, because you've already found it)
- Deleting a single node should be fine because its just a search
- Deleting all occurences of a value would require the aforementioned splitting - if I want to delete all occurences of A, I'd have to search both sides of the node if I encountered A, whereas if I kept it strictly `left <= middle < right` (or vise versa) I'd only have to search one side. But it doesn't seem like it'd degenerate
- I think it also lets me always keep the height on the left side no more than +-1 from the heigh on the right side.

I'm wondering if:

- There are any cases where any operations on the tree would degenerate
- This violates any "principles of a BST"
- There's anything else I missed and should consider

I'm doing this in Haskell, if it makes a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already managed to find out yourself, theres nothing fundamentally wrong with having the same key multiple times on the tree.

I think that the biggest problem here is finding out what multiple key-value pairs with the same key mean in your problem domain - after that choosing what to do becomes much more straightforward. For example, storing a list of values in each node instead of a single one might make the search and delete operations less ambiguous and if having multiple values doesnt make sense then perhaps replacing the old value with the new one is more appropriate...

Comment: If they are all going to be the same value, why not store a count instead of a list?

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez: I was thinking about a map-like datastructure instead of a set-like one when writing the answer. But yes, if you only have the keys then storing a count is another possibility.